# ASP.NET Core 3.0 [FromBody] string content returns "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String."

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

Using `[FromBody]` string content on an `ApiController` in ASP.NET Core 3.0 returns a validation error:

```
{"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
 "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.",
 "status":400,
 "traceId":"|9dd96d96-4e64bafba4ba0245.",
 "errors":{"$":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."]}}
```

when the client post data with content-type : `application/json`

How do I get the raw json data as a string in my api controller in .NET Core 3.0? Without the client having to update its content type?

Comment: Does this works in .net core 2.1? Post sample of your json.

Comment: I decided to just go with StreamReader and read the Request.Body myself.  Its a new project and havent testet on 2.1, but might have bound the body to JToken in the past instead of string.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Not sure this help but I think they made some change in .net core 3.0 Newtonsoft.JSON package so you can try this

Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package.

In your startup.cs add

`services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();`

Comment: My [FromBody] JSON parameter was returning null after the 3.0 upgrade. This fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Tried with asp .net core 3.1. Face error as *Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 5.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1*

Comment: @Vikram, that's because you're installing version 5.0.0 of the NuGet package. Before installation, select the version to be 3.1.

Comment: doesn't work for NET6

Answer (score 47):

If you are using ASP.NET Core 3.0+ then this has built-in JSON support with `System.Text.Json`. I have used the following and it works without setting the custom input handler.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromBody] JsonElement body)
{

    string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(body);
    return Ok();

}
```

Comment: Well don't forget to import/using System.Text.Json; so JsonElement is recognized

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto `System.Text.Json` should be automatically added if you use it, if not then Visual Studio should recommend it as an addition automatically when it marks the line as an error.

Comment: @TylerH Not everyone is using Visual Studio.

Comment: @IS4 They should be, especially if they are writing ASP.NET code. It's even got a _free_ version. That aside, "include the namespace that provides the functionality you want to use" _should_ go without saying, anyway.

Answer (score 33):

Change `[FromBody] string content` to `[FromBody] object content` and then if you want/need to read as string use `content.ToString()`

Answer (score 8):

If you change the parameter `[FromBody] String value` to `[FromBody] YourType value` it is automatically deserialised for you.

From:

```
// POST api/<SelectiveCallRulesController>
[HttpPost]
public async Task Post([FromBody] String rule)        
{
...
```

To:

```
// POST api/<SelectiveCallRulesController>
[HttpPost]
public async Task Post([FromBody] SelectiveCallRule rule)        
{
...
```

It had me going around until I realised the error message regarding deserialisation is correct!

Comment: The problem is sometimes you can't have the value deserialized, because you don't know exactly what type of object you'll be getting.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this error is:

> System.Text.Json doesn't deserialize non-string values into string properties

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-7-0#non-string-values-for-string-properties)).

That means if you have a controller with the simple `[FromBody] string` argument:

```
[HttpPost("save")]
public async Task Save([FromBody] string content)
{
```

this request will succeed:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "\"abcdefgh\"" https://localhost:5000/save -v
```

but this will fail:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"content\":\"abcdefgh\"}" https://localhost:5000/save -v
```

In fact, a similar error occurs not only for `string` but for other simple types like `int`, `bool`, etc. For example, if you change the argument type to `int` in the code above, then sending JSON `{"content":123}` in the body will give `JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32` error.

To avoid this error either:

- fix the request to pass the argument in the body as `"some string"` (instead of JSON)
- pass argument in request as [FromQuery] or [FromForm]
- or move your argument into the property of some class (don't forget the getter and setter for this member because class fields are not deserialized):

```
public class Content
{
    public string Value { get; set;}
}
...
[HttpPost("save")]
public async Task Save([FromBody] Content content)
{
```

Tested on ASP.NET Core 7.0

Answer (score 1):

I had to write a custom `IInputFormatter` to ensure my body content was always interpreted as a string.

I also was in the situation where updating all of the API clients was infeasible.

The following will ensure that any `[FromBody]` parameters will be interpreted as strings, even if they are not quote-wrapped by the caller.

```
public class JsonStringInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter
{
    public JsonStringInputFormatter() : base()
    {
        SupportedEncodings.Add(UTF8EncodingWithoutBOM);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(UTF16EncodingLittleEndian);

        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);
    }

    public override bool CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        return context.ModelType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(
        InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(
            context.HttpContext.Request.Body,
            encoding))
        {
            return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(
                (await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync()).Trim('"'));
        }
    }
}
```

Trimming quotes from the body allows this to be forwards-compatible for body content that is correctly formatted and quote-wrapped.

Ensure that it is registered in your startup before the `System.Text.Json` formatter:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.InputFormatters.Insert(
            0,
            new JsonStringInputFormatter());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create another class contains your json field.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? How is this posted in the body of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonElement instead of string or object.
{yourcontrollername([FromBody] JsonElement yourJsondata)}

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was working with Angular and NET 6.0

So the controller:

```
    public string? Post([FromBody] string word)
    {
    }
```

and the call from angular:

using

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

the code:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});
```

will mark the petition as json.

```
const body = JSON.stringify("myvalue");

  this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'controller', body, { headers: headers, responseType: 'text', withCredentials: true }).subscribe(result => {
      this.mycontent = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
```

In the above example, The responstype is only because the controller is returning also a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

     
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SaveScreen([FromBody] JObject value)
        {
            JObject result = new JObject();
            _log.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value,Formatting.Indented));
            return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result), "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        }
```

Not sure if it's what you want. but i use this code and get the result I want. I just want to post json string into controller.

Answer (score -2):

You need to convert the Json Object to string and then send it to server. Like JSON.stringify(jsonObj).

Comment: I cant change clients.