# Upgrade GraphQL from .NET core 2.2 to 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql, asp.net-core-3.0, graphiql

I am new to GraphQL, when I try to upgrade .net core version from 2.2 to 3.0

I got problem about UI display on /graphql page when using UseGraphiQl

[image]

API is working normally but the UI is display incorrect.
I googled for find out solutions, but nothing really helpful.

Here is my config for graphql:

```
services.AddRazorPages().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

app.UseGraphiQLServer(new GraphiQLOptions());
app.UseGraphiQl("/graphiql", "/graphql");
app.UseEndpoints(x =>
{
    x.MapControllers();
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I find out the solution:

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

As part of the work to improve the ASP.NET Core shared framework, Json.NET has been removed from the ASP.NET Core shared framework.

To use Json.NET in an ASP.NET Core 3.0 project:

- Add a package reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.
- Update Startup.ConfigureServices to call AddNewtonsoftJson.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if they are changing anything in .net core version 3.0 but you can view my blog [here](https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2019/06/02/building-fullstack-web-app-with-net-core-2-2-angular-8-graphql/)

I'm using `GraphQL.Server.Ui.Playground`

Below is minial config you can see

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        )
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    services.AddGraphQL(x =>
    {
        x.ExposeExceptions = true; //set true only in development mode. make it switchable.
    })
    .AddGraphTypes(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, Seeder seeder)
{
    app.UseGraphQL<DataSchema>();
    app.UseGraphQLPlayground(new GraphQLPlaygroundOptions());

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

The result is the same with GraphiQl

[image]

Edit: This is because Newtonsoft.Json is change in .Net Core 3. You can view my answer here

[ASP.NET Core 3.0 [FromBody] string content returns "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150652/asp-net-core-3-0-frombody-string-content-returns-the-json-value-could-not-be/58155409#58155409)

Comment: Thanks for your response but my application is totally ok in v2.2.

Comment: I am in latest version already 1.2 for graphiql and 3.4.0 for GraphQL.Server.Ui.GraphiQL