# POST request getting JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm making a POST request to API endpoint http://localhost:20779/api/Account and getting the following error.

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ |
> LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."

This is the JSON I'm using to make POST request.

```
{
    "EmailAddress": "hello@example.com",
    "Username": "example",
    "Password": "mypassword",
    "Status": "A",
    "CreatedOn": "2021-08-10 08:00:00"
}
```

The request hits the POST method.

```
namespace HelpDesk.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        // POST api/<AccountController>
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
            var x = string.Empty;
        }
  
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core 3.0 \[FromBody\] string content returns "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150652/asp-net-core-3-0-frombody-string-content-returns-the-json-value-could-not-be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a view model class:

```
public UserViewModel
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

and fix the action:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] UserViewModel model)
{
    return Ok(model.Username);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `[FromBody] string value` to `[FromBody] object content`
and then if you want to read as string use `content.ToString()`