# Not able to handle Axios Post request from .NET 7.0 controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, axios, asp.net-core-7.0

My website makes this request:

```
const httpLink = 'https://www.myServer.com' + '/api/DBCom/saveInformation';   

             var postAxios = axios({
              method: 'post',
              url:     httpLink,
              params: {tableName: tableName},
              headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
              data: rowInfo
           }                                  
                 ).then(function (response) {
                  console.log(response);
                  // alert(response);
                  // answer = true;
            
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert('Error' + error.response.data);
                answer = false;
                // location.replace(getServerInfo());
              
              });
```

My C# .NET 7.0 controller looks like this:

```
[Route("api/[Controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DBComController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("Index")]
    public string Index()
    {
        return "hello all";
    } 
    
    [HttpPost("saveInformation")]
    public string saveInformation([FromBody] string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        return "hello from post";
    }
}
```

I know the controller is being found as the `Index` get call works. However, for the POST I am getting an error:

User.js:265

```
    POST https:  ############/api/DBCom/saveInformation 400 (Bad Request)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:256
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:146
wrap @ bind.js:5
User.onBlurOfTextbox @ User.js:265
onBlur @ User.js:371
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
Show 20 more frames
Show less
User.js:278 AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you setting the proper `Content-Type` for the `POST` request? If you pass JSON in your POST body, it should be `Content-Type : application/json`

Comment: Well, I was using the previous Axios call with a Scala controller and no content-type field was needed. Maybe this is important for dotnet... hmmm

Comment: A `GET` request needs no content-type, since it sends no content. A `POST` request however **does** send content, so you need to define what type it is. And **NO**, that's **NOT** a .NET thing - that's basic HTTP requirements ....

Answer (score 1):

As **marc_s**  said, to post JSON data to the server, you need to provide the JSON data in the HTTP POST request body and pass the "Content-Type: application/json" request header. The Content-Type request header specifies the media type for the resource in the body.

Add the header like:

```
var postAxios = axios({
                   method: 'post',
                   url:     httpLink,
                   params: {tableName: tableName},
                   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' },    
                   data: rowInfo
                })
```

result:

[image]

Comment: I am still getting a bad request message

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is that it is necessary to use System.Text.Json and instead of

```
saveInformation([FromBody] string value)
```

Use

```
saveInformation([FromBody] JsonDocument value)
```

or something similar as

```
 saveInformation([FromBody] JsonElement value)
```

Ref:  [ASP.NET Core 3.0 [FromBody] string content returns "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150652/asp-net-core-3-0-frombody-string-content-returns-the-json-value-could-not-be)